# How to read from runtime created file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, file

Tried to allow the choice of a file name from a spinner and then my app will show the content of the specific file chosen, but it doesn't work this way.
Any suggestions?

The exception is:     java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "R.raw.number_1"
at line                         is=getResources().openRawResource(Integer.parseInt(s));

```
   s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           for(int i=0;i<=workouts.size();i++) {
               if (i == position) {
                   String s="R.raw."+workouts.get(i);
                   is=getResources().openRawResource(Integer.parseInt(s));
                   isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                   br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                   String t, all="";
                   try {
                       while((t = br.readLine()) != null)
                           all +=t +"\n\n";
                       br.close();
                       workoutContent.setText(all);
                   }
                   catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       @Override
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       }
   });
```

Comment: Which bit fails exactly? What exception do you get?

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "R.raw.number_1"

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse the literal string `R.raw.number_1` as an int, when it isn't a number. It's a string.

Instead of parsing the string, you need to lookup the identifier (`number_1`) using `getIdentifier`, and then use that:

```
int resourceIdentifier = getResources().getIdentifier(workouts.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
is = getResources().openRawResource(resourceIdentifier);
isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Comment: But is it possible to do the same thing if the file is saved at the phone's data, and not in raw?